# Retrieve value from IndexedDB using Dexie and Svelte

Tags: javascript, promise, svelte, indexeddb, dexie

I don't understand how I can get a value from IndexedDB using Dexie. Database is all good in 'application' tab in inspect tool. Total newbie, so please be understanding.

My db.js

```
import Dexie from "dexie";

export const db = new Dexie("myDatabase");
db.version(2).stores({
  history: "++id, daterange, days",
  storage: "id, name, value"
});

db.on("populate", function () {
  db.storage.add({
    id: 0,
    name: "total",
    value: 20
  });
  db.storage.add({
    id: 1,
    name: "left",
    value: 20
  });
});
db.open();
```

App.svelte

```
<script>
  import Counter from "./src/Counter.svelte";
  import New from "./src/New.svelte";
  import History from "./src/History.svelte";
  import { liveQuery } from "dexie";
  import { db } from "./src/db";

  let total = liveQuery(() =>
    db.storage
      .where("name")
      .equals("total")
      .value.then(function(a) {
        totals = a;
      })
  );

  let left = 25;
</script>

<style>
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<main>
    <Counter daysLeft={left} daysMax={total}/>
    <New />
    <History />
</main>
```

Whatever I try, object with `daysMax={total}` outputs `undefined`, `[object Object]` or something like `[Dexie object Object]`. I just want to get `20` from db, as seen in db.js:

```
db.on("populate", function () {
  db.storage.add({
    id: 0,
    name: "total",
    value: 20
  });
```

(This all works and is visible in indexedDb)
I also tried `daysMax={$total}`

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hawking-jgtbv5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, your DB setup and initial write operations are done correctly. The issue is with your query:

```js
  let total = liveQuery(() =>
    db.storage
      .where("name")
      .equals("total")
      .value.then(function(a) {
        totals = a;
      })
  );
```

First of all, the [WhereClause](https://dexie.org/docs/WhereClause/WhereClause) part of your query (`db.storage.where("name").equals("total")`) returns a [Collection](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection), which, to quote the documentation:

> Represents a collection of database objects. Note that it will not contain any objects by itself. Instead, it yields a preparation for how to execute a DB query. A query will be executed when calling methods that returns a Promise, such as toArray(), keys(), count() or each().

So you cannot simply dereference `.value` as you do in your code. You must instead use one of the methods provided by Collection. Since in your use case you only ever expect a single match to be found in the database, I would recommend [Collection.first()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.first()) here, which returns a Promise that eventually resolves to the data you're querying.

So your query should instead look like this:

```js
  let total = liveQuery(() =>
    db.storage
      .where("name")
      .equals("total")
      .first()
  );
```

Next is the way you use `liveQuery`. What [liveQuery()](https://dexie.org/docs/liveQuery()) does is it turns a Promise (which you will now receive from the previous step) into an Observable. As stated in the documentation:

> The Svelte Store Contract is a subset of the Ecmascript Observable specification draft which makes the return value of liveQuery() a fully valid Svelte Store by itself.

Meaning here that `total` will in fact behave like a [Svelte (readable) store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store), that can be subscribed to, or accessed with the shorthand `$` syntax. This means that `$total` will hold - once the query completes and the promise resolves - the database object that matches your query.

And because it is an Observable (and thus a Svelte store), any updates made to the database record will be immediately reflected in the value of `$total`.

The last thing to be done is to access the `value` property of the database object. <del>Because `$total` will initially be `undefined` while the query runs and the promise resolves, I would also add a conditional.</del> For this I would recommend using a small reactive declaration to keep things tidy, picking a variable name that will allow you to use shorthand prop notation, combined with a conditional to only display the counter when the query has resolved:

```js
<script>
    // ...your existing script code with updated query...
    $: daysMax = $total?.value // undefined until the query resolves, actual value once the query has resolved
</script>

<main>
    {#if daysMax !== undefined}
        <Counter daysLeft={left} {daysMax} />
    {/if}
    <New />
    <History />
</main>
```

[Forked, working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shape-b72p0e)

Comment: That's super helpful! I was confused for three days, I'm thankful for such a detailed explanation. There's not so many sources covering Dexie and even less in Svelte.

Comment: Glad I could help! I updated the last paragraph a little bit, for what I believe is a better way to access `.value`. Also fixed the CodeSandbox, as I apparently had forgotten to save my changes xD Sorry for that.